# Linux Mint 18 wifi not working when resuming after suspend

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, suspend

Linux Mint 18.3 (64-bit with Cinnamon) freshly installed on an HP Pavilion 15 laptop. It's been working flawlessly so far except for when I close the lid and suspend it, then later open it up and resume using it. The `iwlwifi` adapter becomes unusable at that point until I reboot.

I've tried every solution I saw for similar issues for this. Logging out and back in doesn't help. Trying to switch into airplane mode doesn't help. In particular, the most common solution was restarting the network manager service, but that also has no effect.

I noticed when I tried `ifconfig up` was that it said it couldn't because of RF-kill. Checking `rfkill` shows that the wireless LAN is hard blocked.

Before:

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

After:

```
$ rfkill list
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes   <----
```

I'm getting tired of having to reboot the system to get this working again after I close the laptop. Any other ideas to try?

Comment: What happens if you try to unload the wifi kernel module?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro on `sudo rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi`, the `rfkill list` becomes empty. `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` brings it back, still hard blocked. Restarting the network manager service still has no effect.

Comment: Available BIOS upgrade? If there is, I would advise you to install it.